# MongoDB: Profiling - Remove

Tags: mongodb, profiling

I create a separate collection nightly refreshing data, and the first thing I do is remove all the entries which are currently in it.  Through profiling I find that this remove command can take upwards of 101190 milliseconds..

Is this normal? Is there something I should be doing in order to speed this query up? it seems that just emptying a collection should be fairly instant.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a `remove()` with no filter condition can be very slow, since each document must be removed from the collection data files and any indexes which exist (including the default index on _id).

If you are removing all the documents in a collection, and especially if you are only using the default index or you can re-create your indexes easily from within your application code, you can `drop()` the collection instead, and then begin adding your new data.

You can further minimize the time that the collection appears to be empty or partially full by using the [`renameCollection` command](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/renameCollection+Command) like (in pseudo-Python):

```
for new_record in new_records:
    db.newcollection.insert(new_record)

for index_spec in index_specs:
    db.newcollection.ensure_index(index_spec)

db.oldcollection.drop()
db.command('renameCollection', 'newcollection', to='oldcollection')
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much for your insite into this; I wasn't aware that removing can be so time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

dcrosta has described the reason why `remove()` could be slow, and that's also why that's not a good idea to clear all data in a collection.

Since you can create or drop collection on the fly in MongoDB, a much quicker and better way is to simply drop the collection, then insert new documents (collection will be re-created automatically).

So just issue a `db.collname.drop()` first.